# Am I eligible to get PMP Certification?

Tags: management

I have done my Masters in Business Administration with HR and Marketing as my Specialization. It's been four years. I am currently working as Lead Recruiter with  a Reputed Organization. So, I just want to know whether or not I am eligible to get the PMP Certification. If so, what would be the channel to get it done?

Please help me; what would be the best way to get the certification done and what are the pros and cons I will be facing?

This would really be a great help to change my domain.

Comment: You must ask PMI; nobody but PMI can tell you if you are eligible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about project management.

Answer (score 2):

You must work on project mode and meet the requirements noticed in the PMBOK. here is the requirements from the PMBOK:

(PMBOK® Guide—Fifth Edition)

[image]

Regards :)